# Is there any way that I can upload office add-in using rest api?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, azure-powershell, outlook-web-addins

#### What I have tried ?

I have tried using Power Shell to upload office add-in by referring following link,
[Use the Centralized Deployment PowerShell cmdlets to manage add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/use-the-centralized-deployment-powershell-cmdlets-to-manage-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide)

but I ended up receiving,

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-OrganizationAddIn -ManifestPath 'D:\Manifest\manifest.xml' -Locale 'en-US' 

Extracting Add-In's manifest...
**The Add-In you are trying to upload supports Single Sign On and to upload the Add-In you need to use Office 365 Admin Center.
Press Enter to consent to the Add-In in Office 365 Admin Center.**
If there are any issues you can go to
https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home?assetid=lob&mktcmpid=powershell#/Settings/ServicesAndAddIns
And go to Settings > Services & Add-Ins
```

Also, the URL mentioned in above message, which is, *https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home?assetid=lob&mktcmpid=powershell#/Settings/ServicesAndAddIns* is old. We no longer upload add-in from this endpoint.

---

Additionally, I do have referred,
[Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish)

As, since it is an Outlook add-in, it cancelled out uploading it via SharePoint app catalog.

**Is there any other way that I can do it using command shell or rest APIs ?
Additionally, is there any restriction to upload add-in which supports Single sign on via PowerShell ?**

Comment: Have you gone through these Outlook add-in rest api documentation  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/apis, Does it helpful ?

Comment: The url is old. We created a action item to fix the url. We don't have a way for Admins to install addins other than MAC portal or Powershell.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Here, you did mentioned that we can upload addins using PowerShell, but I am not able to do centralize deployment of "Outlook add-in" which has SSO enabled. It is showing me, "The Add-In you are trying to upload supports Single Sign On and to upload the Add-In you need to use Office 365 Admin Center." message.